# How to iterate a webscraping script over daily time series object in order to create a daily time series of data from the webpage

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, time-series

Thanks for taking a look at my question. I have created a script using BeautifulSoup and Pandas which scrapes data on projections from the Federal Reserve's website. The projections come out once a quarter (~ 3 mos.). I'd like to write a script which creates a daily time series and checks the Federal Reserve website once a day, and if there has been a new projection posted, the script would add that to the time series. If there has not been an update, then the script would just append the time series with the last valid, updated projection.

From my initial digging, it seems there are outside sources I can use to "trigger" the script daily, but I would prefer to keep everything purely python.

The code I have written to accomplish the scraping is as so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import wget
import pandas as pd 

# Starting url and the indicator (key) for links of interest
url = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm" 
key = '/monetarypolicy/fomcprojtabl'

# Cook the soup
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

# Create the tuple of links for projection pages
projections = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(key)):
    projections.append(link["href"])

# Create a tuple to store the projections 
decfcasts = []
for i in projections:
    url = "https://www.federalreserve.gov{}".format(i)
    file = wget.download(url)
    df_list = pd.read_html(file)
    fcast = df_list[-1].iloc[:,0:2]
    fcast.columns = ['Target', 'Votes']
    fcast.fillna(0, inplace = True)
    decfcasts.append(fcast)
```

So far, the code I have written places everything in a tuple, but there is no time/date index for the data. I've been thinking of pseudo-code to write, and my guess is it will look something like

```
Create daily time series object
    for each day in time series:
        if day in time series = day in link:
            run webscraper
        other wise, append time series with last available observation
```

At least, this is what I have in mind. The final time series should probably end up looking fairly "clumpy" in the sense that there will be a lot of days with the same observation, and then when a new projection comes out, there will be a "jump" and then a lot more repetition until the next projection comes out.

Obviously, any help is tremendously appreciated. Thanks ahead of time, either way!

Comment: Can you share url with data? Maybe it is possible to get date/time from there using BeautifulSoap and append them together (url and date) to projections

Comment: Dear Hubert, thanks for taking a look. I left out the url from the script in order to try and make it look as clean as possible. Of course, I'd be happy to share the url. It is https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm   Finally, the relevant links on that webpage indeed contain the date/time data. For example, the last link that is relevant to this is https://www.federalreserve.govmonetarypolicy/fomcprojtabl20190320.htm   The time/date data in this link is 03/20/2019.

Comment: Hubert, I added the url and link key back into the code per your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited code for you. Now it get date from url. Date is saved as period in dataframe. Only when date is not present in dataframe (restored from pickle) it is processed and appended.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import wget
import pandas as pd

# Starting url and the indicator (key) for links of interest
url = "https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomccalendars.htm"
key = '/monetarypolicy/fomcprojtabl'

# Cook the soup
page = requests.get(url)
data = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

# Create the tuple of links for projection pages
projections = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(key)):
    projections.append(link["href"])

# past results from pickle, when no pickle init empty dataframe
try:
    decfcasts = pd.read_pickle('decfcasts.pkl')
except FileNotFoundError:
    decfcasts = pd.DataFrame(columns=['target', 'votes', 'date'])


for i in projections:

    # parse date from url
    date = pd.Period(''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', i)), 'D')

    # process projection if it wasn't included in data from pickle
    if date not in decfcasts['date'].values:

        url = "https://www.federalreserve.gov{}".format(i)
        file = wget.download(url)
        df_list = pd.read_html(file)
        fcast = df_list[-1].iloc[:, 0:2]
        fcast.columns = ['target', 'votes']
        fcast.fillna(0, inplace=True)

        # set date time
        fcast.insert(2, 'date', date)
        decfcasts = decfcasts.append(fcast)

# save to pickle
pd.to_pickle(decfcasts, 'decfcasts.pkl')
```